# Javascript - Insert DIV elements into DOM but its not loading

Tags: javascript, html

I'm able to insert the element into the dom when I look at the page source but the page doesn't display anything. Looking at the network tab in chrome dev tools the http request for the url's doesn't get requested at all for jquery or phaser or game.js.

Is there something wrong here?

This is the div that I'm trying to insert element into

```
<div id="c12" style="width:2px;height:2px;overflow:visible"><div>
```

and here is the getElement code:

```
document.getElementById("c12").innerHTML='
                <div id=game>
                  <div id=content>
                  </div>
                  <script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js>
                  </script>
                </div>
                <script src=test/js/phaser.min.js></script>
                <script src=test/js/game.js></script>
        '
```

But if I add a image source anywhere in the above code, it works fine and I can see the http request and also the image in the browser.

The path is correct as I can access it using mysite.com/test/js/game.js.

Comment: Why would it display anything?
Assuming you've fixed single-quote into back-tick:
It loads divs and scripts.
Unless any of those divs have border/background/etc. and/or the script produces a visible change.
Indent: it will help you and anyone looking at your code understand better what you did (I've done that for you here).
I'd like to recommend learning [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) = an alternative to setting `innerHTML`.

Comment: If you use single-quote, add a back-slash (`\\`) at the end of EACH line.
It will create a string as if it was on one line.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that the reason but change it from ' to ` like so:

```
document.getElementById("c12").innerHTML=`
                <div id=game>
                  <div id=content>
                  </div>
                  <script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js>
                  </script>
                </div>
                <script src=test/js/phaser.min.js></script>
                <script src=test/js/game.js></script>
        `
```

The reason is that ' only will include the first line while ` will let you include all inside the backticks

Comment: Good job catching that!
I up-voted your answer, edited indentation to be consistent with my indentation edit of the question, suggested asker to look into `document.createElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Script should be inserted as an element. Solution below

```js
var script1 = document.createElement('script')
var script2 = document.createElement('script')
var script3 = document.createElement('script')
      

script1.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js";
script2.src = "test/js/phaser.min.js";
script3.src = "test/js/game.js";

document.getElementById("c12").innerHTML=`
<div id=game>
    <div id=content>
    </div>
</div>               
`
document.getElementById('game').appendChild(script1);
document.getElementById('c12').appendChild(script2);
document.getElementById('c12').appendChild(script3);
```

```html
<div id="c12" style="width:2px;height:2px;overflow:visible"><div>
```